# How to use cidr_block and source_security_group_id in ingress terraform rule

Tags: terraform

i need to use both `cidr_block` and `source_security_group_id` in inbound rule using `terraform`.

When i am using the same it is giving the error:

```
cidr block conflict interface [10.0.1.0/24]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify multiple `ingress` rules per `aws_security_group` resource, as per the documentation:

> ingress - (Optional) Can be specified multiple times for each ingress rule.

You can read more about this [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/security_group.html) in the Terraform documentation.

A working example of using both CIDR and security group source IDs might look like this:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "security_group" {
  name   = "My security group"
  vpc_id = "${var.vpc_id}"

  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["123.45.76.89/32"]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port       = 22
    to_port         = 22
    protocol        = "tcp"
    security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.some_other_server.id}"]
  }

  // .. egress rules
  // .. tags, etc
}
```

If you're already using multiple `ingress` rules, it's likely that your CIDR blocks are simply overlapping.